# Why Do I have to run npm install everytime I create a new angular 2 project?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

Everytime I make a new angular 2 project it says 
"node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install"

Comment: You don't need to install every time. its one time setup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Dependencies

Each project has different dependencies. A project might use a library for handling `dates`, while another project uses a library to display a `modal`.

In your angular project, you have a file called `package.json`. this file is responsible for keeping track of your project's **dependencies**.

When you run `npm install`, **Node Package Manager**, or **npm** for short, will download those dependencies and put them in `node_modules` folder.

Comment: because each angular app might have different dependencies. and dependencies are resolved relative to your angular app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run npm install to install the dependencies. May be refer to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "automatically". What do you think should trigger installing the dependencies for an app? Every app/project will have a different set of dependencies out of which some are dependencies while others are devDependencies(used only during development) . Per npmjs.com, at this moment, there are 520,400(and counting) npm modules. I'm assuming that count is only for public modules and doesn't include private modules. Are you suggesting, Angular should come shipped with all these hundreds of thousands of packages?

Comment: then why does everybody else say that in angular cli there shouldn't be any need to run npm install as it is done when you ng new a project

Comment: Didn't realize you were using angular cli. That should have been clarified in the question. Anyways, are you sure you're not using `--skip-install` or `-si` or `--skipInstall` along with your ng new command? Can you run ng new with `--verbose` or `-v`, so it outputs more logging if there was an issue?

Comment: I got the same exact error today when I forgot to cd into the directory that was created by `ng new` command.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Angular CLI to build your application instead. Then you won't need to use `npm install` when building a new application.

See this for more information: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

Comment: i installed it 
it worked then
then I opened cmd today made a new project and it generated the same error **node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`**

Comment: Did you use the CLI to create the new project? Did you navigate down into the created folder before attempting to run it? You need to be within the folder containing the package.json file before you attempt to run the application. (And if you used the CLI to generate the app you should not need to run npm install.)

Comment: when I run npm install it creates that node_modules folder

Answer (score 0):

Once you run the `ng new my-project`. Just give it some time to install the dependencies into the node_modules folder, which shows the below message.

Installing packages for tooling via npm

You will get the following message once it is done:

Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Project 'my-project' successfully created.

Now try running the `ng serve`. It should work fine.